# Map query result to class(sub-class)

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

Question on query result to objects mapping in C#.

Frontend expect from backend JSON like this:

```json
unBookedOrders: [{
    orderId: 865470,
    orderCollectionNumber: 6114353,
    orderAddress: {
        address: 'Gamlestadsvägen 123',
        city: 'Göteborg'
    },
    customer: {
        firmName: 'Firm Name',
        agentName: 'Agent Name'
    },
},
...
]
```

In backend for this purpose I have the following classes:

```
public class Order
{
    public int orderId { get; set; }
    public int orderCollectionNumber { get; set; }
    public OrderAddress orderAddress { get; set; }
    public Customer customer { get; set; }
}
public class OrderAddress
{
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
}
public class Customer
{
    public string firmName { get; set; }
    public string agentName { get; set; }
}
```

All these data come from query:

```
var orders = await _session.QueryAsync<Orders>(@"
    SELECT
        o.Id AS OrderId,
        oc.OrderCollectionNumber,
        bo.AddressLine1 AS Address,
        bo.AddressCity AS City,
        c.FirstName,
        c.AgentName
from Table1 opp ...
WHERE ...
```

It maps good to orderId and orderCollectionNumber.

Question: how to map OrderAddress and Customer to query result?

Comment: In the Dapper site you should look at the example for [MultiMapping](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper#multi-mapping)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Dapper to get this done (example has products  and categories instead of orders and addresses):

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var sql = @"SELECT ProductID, ProductName, p.CategoryID, CategoryName
                FROM Products p 
                INNER JOIN Categories c ON p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID";
                
    var products = await connection.QueryAsync<Product, Category, Product>(sql, (product, category) => {
        product.Category = category;
        return product;
    }, 
    splitOn: "CategoryId" );
    
    products.ToList().ForEach(product => Console.WriteLine($"Product: {product.ProductName}, Category: {product.Category.CategoryName}"));
    
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

See: https://www.learndapper.com/relationships for more detail